# How to make a subclass based on an entity in core data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I was following a few tutorials on youtube to get specific things done in my own project. This one in specific: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=da6W7wDh0Dw&t=1121s

He instructed the users to make a subclass for your entities. I did this and was hoping for the same thing he got. However, I got tons of errors...I deleted my .xcdatamodeld file and planned to do it over because I might have just done something wrong and after I deleted it, these errors went away. Not sure why that would be? Nonetheless I redid the process and made it simpler but the same exact thing happened.

Here is the code that was automatically generated when I created the subclasses.

for CoreDataClass file

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(GeneralEvaluation)
public class GeneralEvaluation: NSManagedObject {

}
```

I receive an error saying "Invalid declaration of 'GeneralEvaluation'".

for CoreDataProperties file

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension GeneralEvaluation {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<GeneralEvaluation> {
        return NSFetchRequest<GeneralEvaluation>(entityName: "GeneralEvaluation");
    }

    @NSManaged public var scenarioNumber: Int16
    @NSManaged public var totalScore: Int16
    @NSManaged public var washScore: Int16
    @NSManaged public var idScore: Int16
    @NSManaged public var courseNumber: String?

}
```

I receive multiple errors here.

- "'GeneralEvaluation' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context" (this is for both lines `extension GeneralEvaluation` and the line beginning with `@nonobj`)
- "'NSManaged' on an instance property or method"
- "Extensions may not contained stored properties" (both of these errors apply to all lines starting with `@NSManaged`)

Here is a screenshot of my model...

[image: Here is a screenshot of my model...]

What could I have done that destroyed this process to go so smoothly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using iOS 10. Please check they have update CoreData API. With Codegenerations. Check in iOS 10 core data update.
1.Select Entity.
2.Add Attributes.
3.Now Select Entity and on right side pannel press Command+Alt(Option)+3.You will be navigated to "Show data model Inspector".
4.In this pannel you will be able to find "Codegen" under "class".It's a Dropdown Button.
5.It will provide three options 
a)Manual/None
b)Class Definition
c)Category Extension.
If you select Manula/None than you have to generate subclasses Manually.
or if you have selected Class Definition than there is no need to generate Subclasses because xcode will automatically keeps track of it.[image]

[image]

Comment: I looked for updates on my computer, would that be a system update or for Xcode?

Comment: Also I'm using iOS 10.12.3

Comment: Check in WWDC I don't remember the session number. Just search for core data.

Comment: @AmberRebeccaHowe Did you meant the macOS 10.12.3 ?

Comment: @GowthamNamuri, it may be working now. I am going to mess with it and let you know.

Comment: I'm still not entirely certain what I was actually having issues with before, but I have a hunch that there is a necessary closing out of Xcode for the classes to actually be generated? I ended up adding another entity and it wasn't recognizing the class until I closed Xcode out and reopened it. Not sure, but I'm just glad it worked and I have hope to get the project done on time. Thanks, @GowthamNamuri, very insightful and helpful reply. you get answer of the year.